# ADmad/JwtAuth authentication integration test controller Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, integration-testing, cakephp-3.0, jwt

I'm currently try to perform an integration test for a controller that is only accessible when there has been send a request with Authorization: Bearer *token* (I'm using the ADmad/JwtAuth plugin). Here is the code for test controller:

```
public function testViewShouldPass(){
    $accessToken = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjE2LCJleHAiOjE0NTgyNDEzNDF9.pJ2q_t6d2wBPF4Ie_gOx-_o0zWfDB0mgYeAan4WaSdQ';
    $this->configRequest([
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ]
    ]);
    $data = $this->get('/api/pictures/1.json');
    $this->assertResponseOk(); // will throw an unauthorized exception
    $this->assertResponseContains('Pictures');
}
```

How can I make sure that the test method isn't throwing an unauthorized exception? I'm aware that the token needs somehow to be mocked but I have no clue how this is done since I'm fairly new to unit/integration testing (both in general and in Cakephp).

Comment: You can't mock the token but you can mock `JwtAuthenticate::payload()` to return an ArrayObject with valid data.

Comment: Okay, I will check that soon. I've temporary blocked the entire token procedure in my unit/integration tests.

Comment: does `JwtAuthenticate::payload()` provide the token directly?